# In Jquery how do you find out the 'eq' of an element of what is being clicked?

Tags: jquery

When one of the divs inside 'uploadChoice' is clicked, how can I ascertain which one is clicked? Can I return an 'eq' value somehow?

```
 <div id=uploadChoice>
     <div>Text</div>
     <div>Image</div<
    <div>Text & Image</div>
</div>



$("#uploadChoice div").click(function(){
    //insert code here! :)   
});
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
$('#uploadChoice div').click(function(event) {
  var index = $(this).index();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

An easier alternative that does not require duplicating a selector is the following

```
$('#uploadChoice div').click(function(event) {
  var index = $(this).prevAll().length;
});
```

Comment: Nice! Sadly i'll leave brianng the marks as he got to me quicker :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: The marks is the best solution. Not fastest:) Imagine you came here via google. Which answer would you want to see!

Comment: Definately brianng's now you've said that ;) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add selectors as well, and pass "$(this)" as argument:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.testbutton', function () {
  
  var index = $('div.example > div.xyz').find('button.testbutton').index($(this));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the div with

```
$("#uploadChoice div").click(function(){
    var choice = $(this).html;
}
```

And then just do a switch statement or some nested ifs.

Personally though, I'd add an ID to each of the divs and just check the ID of the clicked element.

Comment: Can I ask why this was voted down? It certainly takes care of what the original poster was asking for. In fact, it provides two options for identifying which option a user clicked on.

Also, this solution would allow the user to re-order their buttons without having to change any code, as it uses the value (or ID) of the buttons rather than their relative position.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. The OP was looking specifically for a way to do this using 'eq', so my solutions didn't satisfy that. Nevermind.